# Conditional convergence of Artin $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $k$ be a number field and $V$ a non-trivial irreducible Artin representation over $k$. Consider the associated Artin $L$-function with corresponding Euler product decomposition $L(V,s)= \prod_v L_v(V,s)$ where the product is over all non-archimedean places of $k$, for $\mathrm{re} \, s > 1$.

Then I'm fairly sure that one should have
$$L(V,1) = \prod_v L_v(V,1)$$
however I can't find this in the literature. It should follow from the analogous result for Hecke $L$-functions and the usual argument via Brauer induction. Any indication where to find this in the literature would be ideal!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known that $L(V,s)$ is analytic and non-vanishing in $\Re(s)\geq 1$. Equivalently, $\log L(V,s)$ is analytic in $\Re(s)\geq 1$. Note that $\log L(V,s)$ is given by an absolutely convergent Dirichlet series $D(V,s)$ in $\Re(s)>1$. This Dirichlet series $D(V,s)$ has bounded coefficients, it is supported on prime powers, and the contribution of a given non-archimedean place $v$ equals $\log L_v(V,s)$. In particular,
$$\log L(V,s)=\sum_v\log L_v(V,s),\qquad\Re(s)>1.\tag{1}$$
By Ingham's Tauberian theorem (for which Newman gave a [simple proof](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1980.11995126) in 1980), $D(V,s)$ converges in $\Re(s)\geq 1$. Hence, by Theorem 1.1 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I (CUP, 2006), $D(V,s)$ is continuous in $\Re(s)\geq 1$. It follows that
$$\log L(V,s)=D(V,s),\qquad \Re(s)\geq 1.\tag{2}$$
On the right-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$, the contributions of prime powers that are not primes converge absolutely for $\Re(s)>1/2$, hence they are equal, while the contributions of primes are identical Dirichlet series. Hence in fact
$$\log L(V,s)=\sum_v\log L_v(V,s),\qquad\Re(s)\geq 1.$$
Equivalently,
$$L(V,s)=\prod_v L_v(V,s),\qquad\Re(s)\geq 1.$$